# htaccess problem with filename

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

when I first set up my site I decided to add `index.html` to the URL but now I have problems with when people remove the `index.html` and try and access the folder...

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/index.html archive.php?mid=$1-$2
```

So when `archives/07/2009/` it will cause an error, how can I avoid this error? 
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `index.html` optional in your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(?:index\.html)?$ archive.php?mid=$1-$2
```

Also, in your original rewrite rule, you forgot your end of string anchor `$`. I've added it above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule witht an optional `index.html`:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(index\.html)?$ archive.php?mid=$1-$2
```

But I recommend you to stick just with one of both notations, with or without the trailing `index.html` and redirect if wrong:

```
# remove index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# add index.html
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1/index.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: **@Gumbo:** You might want to make `index\.html` a non-capturing group.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: Non-capturing groups are only available since Apache 2.